# Python subprocess Messy output

Tags: python, subprocess

With the following code:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['wmic', 'PATH', 'Win32_videocontroller', 'GET', 'description'])
    print(output , "\n")
```

I get the next output:

```
b'Description                \r\r\nNVIDIA GeForce 710M        \r\r\nIntel(R) HD Graphics 4000  \r\r\n\r\r\n'
```

When I use the commando `wmic path win32_videocontroller get desription`in my CMD I get only the videocard info back. Is this possible in python aswell? With out the /r/r/r/r things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the argument "universal_newlines=True" when you call the function:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['wmic', 'PATH', 'Win32_videocontroller',  'GET', 'description'], universal_newlines=True)
print(output , "\n")
```

Comment: why would you call `str(bytes_object)` here, why would you suggest it to a newbie? The second code example should be the only one in your answer. @joey: I hope that you've used `universal_newlines=True` solution that enables the text mode (why `text_mode` is spelled as `universal_newlines` is not clear).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Good point.  Removed the hacky call at the start :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `translate`

```
print output.translate(None, '\r\n')
```

Comment: TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object |  Is the error message is get:(